# Can't get nrepl working in Emacs

Tags: ubuntu, emacs, clojure, nrepl

I'm running on an Ubuntu machine.  I had `emacs23` installed, but it looks like `nREPL` is designed to work with `emacs24`.  So, I uninstalled `emacs23`, installed `emacs24`.  I removed my existing `.emacs` file and `.emacs.d` directory.

Then I ran `M-x package-list-packages` and installed `clojure-mode` and `nrepl`.

I created a Clojure project with `lein new foobar` and then tried to open the default `core.clj` file.  It puts me in Clojure mode automatically, but if I type `M-x nrepl-jack-in` (while in the `core.clj` buffer), it says `Starting nREPL server...`, but I never see any buffer named `*nrepl*` (which, based on reading the documentation, is the expected result).  I just see the `Starting nREPL server...` in the minibuffer indefinitely.

Now, a buffer named `*nrepl-server*` **is** created and it says:

```
REPL started; server listening on localhost port 5871
Exception Unsupported option(s) supplied: :headless  clojure.core/load-libs (core.clj:5266)
clojure.core=>
```

But it doesn't seem like this is very useful (I can't seem to cause it to eval anything in that buffer?!?).

I tried Googling on this, but I couldn't find anybody who seemed to have this problem.  I'd like to play around with Clojure (and `core.logic` in particular), but this is a complete non-starter. :-(

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So, it turns out the issue was that my version of Ubuntu installed Leinengen 1.7.1 via `apt-get` but if [I upgrade to version 2](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/wiki/Upgrading), the issue went away.

In summary, the issue is that `lein` version 2+ is required here but if you have a lower version you really don't get any visible indication of what is wrong (unless you count the exception thrown in `*nrepl-server*`, which isn't normally visible).

Answer (score 2):

Next time you can also try to start the nrepl-server via `lein repl` in a separate shell. This way you can see if and on what port nrepl is running. In Emacs you can then do M-x nrepl and connect to the right nrepl server instance.